# Can not open Excel Workbook in ASP classic with Excel.Application

Tags: excel, vbscript, asp-classic, com

I have a Windows 2016 Server and I have installed and activated Office 2013 64bit in it.

I have a classic ASP application that is trying to open an Excel workbook like this:

```
<%
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\intranet\web\Libro1.xlsx")

%>
```

I'm aware that this kind of Office automation is discouraged by Microsoft but this is a legacy app that I've inherited and has to manage to make it work on Windows 2016.

If I execute this piece of code as a VBS script there is no issue but if I try to execute it as an ASP page i get:

> Microsoft Office Excel error '800a03ec' Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'C:\intranet\web\Libro1.xlsx'.
>   There are several possible reasons:
>   • The file name or path does not exist.
>   • The file is being used by another program. (...)

I have discarded all the suggested reasons, I have also checked that if I really use a file that does not exist the error message is different.

I'm running my ASP application pool as user "Administrator" (Administrador in my spanish installation).

I have given permissions for everyone in all three sections of the permissions for Microsoft Excel DCOM Configuration entry in components services.

I have checked an installed updates in my operating system and my office package.

I'm running out of ideas, any reasonable clue will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

## Recommendations for Setting up Websites in IIS

Things to consider while setting up IIS websites

- Anonymous Access Account
- Application Pool
- NTFS Permissions

### Setting up an Anonymous Account

- #### Method One - Use `ApplicationPoolIdentity` Instead of `IUSR`

  > The `ApplicationPoolIdentity` is a special term for one of the corresponding `IIS AppPool\<AppPoolAccounts>` in the `IIS_IUSRS` security group.

  The reason is it ties the security context to the Application Pool rather than having the Anonymous Account running as `IUSR` and the Application pool running as `ApplicationPoolIdentity` leaving two security contexts to manage.
- #### Method Two - Use a Custom Account as the Identity of the Application Pool

  For more control use a Custom Account in place of `ApplicationPoolIdentity` in the Application Pool Advanced Settings. Borrowing from *Method One* the Anonymous Account should be set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity` so there is now only one security context to manage.

  The main benefit to this approach over using `IUSR` is you know the password for the Custom Account, whereas IIS controls the `IUSR` password making using it in place of the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` as the Application Pool Identity troublesome.

### Assigning NTFS Permissions

> **WARNING:** UAC *(User Account Control)* can modify the NTFS permissions when running in "[Admin Approval Mode](https://serverfault.com/q/646691/199051)", make sure the setting `User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode` is set to `False` in the Local Group Policy located under `Computer settings\Windows settings\Security settings\Local policies\Security options`.

Depending on the method used for adding an Anonymous Account to a IIS Website there should be one of two accounts added to the Websites root folder;

- Method One - `IIS_IUSRS` (Read Permission)
- Method Two - Custom Account (Read Permission)

At the basic level the Websites root folder should contain the following permissions;

```
| User Account       | Permission            | Notes
| ------------------ | --------------------- | ---------------------
| Administrators     | Full Control          | For File System access.
| <IIS Anonymous>    | Read & Execute        | Either IIS_IUSRS or a Custom Account.
```

> #### Don't Inherit Permissions
>
> Recommend disabling Inheritance on the Websites root folder to stop parent permissions propagating down and overwriting any existing permissions, which can be a costly exercise to restore.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found what the issue was.

Following some pointers about DCOM permissions I had configured "Microsoft.Excel" DCOM configuration permissions using the "Components service" tool. But this wasn't enough.

Today I saw that apart from "Permissions" tab there is an "Identity" tab there. By default it chooses to use the "initial user", which I expected to be the user that is running the IIS application pool. I had already executed the pool with a "real" user so I was not expecting this to be related but when I changed it and selected an specific user there everything started to work.

So to sum-up my solution was:

- Open "Components services administration"
- Find in "DCOM Configs" section the entry related to "Microsoft.Excel" and right click on "Properties".
- In the "Identity" tab set a "real" user that will run Excel when the Interop API's are used.
- In the "Permissions" tab adjust the permission so that the user you have set in the identity tab has the required right

Hope this gives some clues to anyone.

Comment: Are you still using `Administrador` as your `ApplicationPoolIdentity`? If so I wouldn't recommend it due to the security risk it introduces.

Comment: No, no, I'm using "NetworkServices". I was using "Administrator" just during the troubleshooting just to see if it made any difference.